# How to handle the "Traceback" error in python?

Tags: python

Can anyone please tell me How do I remove this **Traceback (most recent call last):** Error in python. I am using python 2.7.9

Take a look over the code.

```
import requests
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-f", '--filename', action="store" ,dest="filee")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

file = options.filee


fopen = open(file, 'r')
for x in fopen.readlines():
    print "Checking for Clickjacking vulnerability\n"
    url = x.strip('\n')
    req = requests.get(url)
    try:
        print "[-]Target:" + url +  " Not vulnerable\n The targeted victim has %s header\n" % (req.headers['X-Frame-Options'])


    except Exception as e:
        print "[+] Target:" + url +" Vulnerable to clickjacking"
```

After running the code successfully I go this error **at the end**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\utkarsh3.py", line 17, in <module>
    req = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 305, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 379, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
```

Which really irritate me. I know there are so many peoples who are already asking this before. But I can't understand it so I ask.

**And please tell me How we beginners handle these errors?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a eli5 fashion, a `Traceback` is a log of what the program was trying to do before actual error happened. Your actual error is `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema`

The line that follows `Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?` describes the exact problem.

```
  File "C:\Python27\utkarsh3.py", line 17, in <module>
req = requests.get(url)
```

These above lines describe where the error started.. 
So, if you go to line 17 of your program you must see this exact same line.

Making a context out of these two things, i get that url is a string that is just `example.com` and not `http://example.com` or something on those lines.

I can only speculate so much on what your code might be. But, feel free to provide your code snippets to explain more.

But, hope this helps you to read future tracebacks.

Edit1 : Now that you added snippet. Try printing `url` just before `requests.get(url)` and see what exactly you are trying to reach. And, if you have the right schema prepended.

Comment: hey, @Vasif  I need a help in urllib. I import that module but I getting this error all time.  **'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'**  I am using python2.

Comment: At this point, i am a proponent of requests library. I would suggest you use that unless you are compelled to use urllib. I can not get to say what you are trying to do with that small error trace. Feel free to raise another question and link it up here. Provide code that is causing the error and the error message. Also, keep in mind and look up what a minimum verifiable complete example is. You will be better at asking questions or you will find your answers even before you ask.